# Magnific Popup Modal issue 'GetInline'

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I get this error

> Property 'getInline' of object [object Object] is not a function

When executing this code

HTML

```
    <div id="test-modal" class="mfp-hide white-popup-block">
            <h1>TITLE</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p><a href="http://google.com">Go back to home page</a> or <a class="popup-modal-dismiss" href="#">Dismiss</a></p>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $.magnificPopup.open({
                    items: {
                        src: '#test-modal',
                    },
                    type: 'inline',
                    preloader: false,
                    modal: true
                }, 0);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: I tested your code, it works correctly, provide an isolated example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late, but it seems that you have not included the inline module (js/inline.js)

See the [file on github](https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/blob/6b7a8088783cbce01034414c1fd2d8e1889093ae/src/js/inline.js)

Hope it helps :)